# rails+radio_button_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In the code below I have used the radio buttons to select one option from Three options,

But, since the name of one radio button is different from other, i can able to select all the three options instead of one

I used this code because, i want to update records with all the three names from text box and its corresponded selected value,

Is there any other work around to do this

**View**

```
<% 1.upto(3) do |i| %>
<%= text_field_tag "fields[#{i}][name]",'' %>
<%= radio_button_tag "fields[#{i}][answer]", '1', false%>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
params[:fields].each do |i, values|
u = Sample.new
u.name = values["name"]
u.answer = values["answer"] ? 1 : 0
u.save
end
```

thanks,

Comment: try using <%= radio_button_tag "fields[#{i}][#{i}_answer]", '1', false%> the  in the controller do u.answer = values["#{i)_answer"] ? 1 : 0
The "i" is the index that will help you associating the radio with the text field.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
<% 1.upto(3) do |i| %>
    <%= text_field_tag "fields[#{i}][name]",'' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag "fields[answer]", '#{i}', false%>
<% end %>
```

This will yield an answer field with a value of 1,2, or 3 depending on which one is selected.

Comment: with this the parameters are passed like this to controller        {"1"=>{"name"=>"aaaaa"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"bbbbb"}, "is_answer"=>"\#{i}"}   with no answer field value

Comment: and while saving, three records are being saved instead of two, with all the answer values as 0

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **nested attributes** may be well suited for your problem.  I'd recommend looking into those instead of the way you are approaching things now.

If you want to just stick with things the way they are you can make things work with a couple adjustments.

For radio buttons to work correctly you need to use a unique value (`i`) for each option:

```
<%= radio_button_tag "answer", i, false%>
```

Then in your controller

```
u.answer = params["answer"] == i ? 1 : 0
```